# Adding OnClickListener makes app crash

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm working on a term project and I'm new to java and android app development. I have experience in other programming languages, though. I'm trying to reverse engineer an app to make it able to connect and send data via bluetooth. I want to make a list with all the available bluetooth devices, a button to turn on/off bluetooth, one for making the phone discoverable for other devices and another to search for unpaired devices. But every time I add an OnClickListener to the onCreate method, the app crashes before it opens. Could anyone help me out?

The source code for the app I am trying to modify can be found here:
https://github.com/pazaan/600SeriesAndroidUploader

Here is the part that seems to makes it crash:

```
lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);


        btnONOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: enabling/disabling bluetooth.");
                enableDisableBT();
            }
        });

        btnStartConnection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startConnection();
            }
        });

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                byte[] bytes = etSend.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
            }
        });
```

And here is all of OnCreate:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Button btnONOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnONOFF);

        btnEnableDisable_Discoverable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiscoverable_on_off);

        lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);

        mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();


        btnStartConnection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartConnection);

        //Broadcasts when bond state changes (ie:pairing)
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4, filter);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        //FUCKUP:
        lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);


        btnONOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: enabling/disabling bluetooth.");
                enableDisableBT();
            }
        });

        btnStartConnection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startConnection();
            }
        });

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                byte[] bytes = etSend.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
            }
        });




        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        RealmResults<PumpStatusEvent> data = mRealm.where(PumpStatusEvent.class)
                .findAllSorted("eventDate", Sort.DESCENDING);
        if (data.size() > 0)
            dataStore.setLastPumpStatus(data.first());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        if (!prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.preference_eula_accepted), false)) {
            stopCgmService();
        }

        // setup preferences
        configurationStore.setPollInterval(Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("pollInterval", Long.toString(MedtronicCnlIntentService.POLL_PERIOD_MS))));
        configurationStore.setLowBatteryPollInterval(Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("lowBatPollInterval", Long.toString(MedtronicCnlIntentService.LOW_BATTERY_POLL_PERIOD_MS))));
        configurationStore.setReducePollOnPumpAway(prefs.getBoolean("doublePollOnPumpAway", false));

        chartZoom = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("chartZoom", "3"));
        configurationStore.setMmolxl(prefs.getBoolean("mmolxl", false));
        configurationStore.setMmolxlDecimals(prefs.getBoolean("mmolDecimals", false));

        // Disable battery optimization to avoid missing values on 6.0+
        // taken from https://github.com/NightscoutFoundation/xDrip/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eveningoutpost/dexdrip/Home.java#L277L298

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            final String packageName = getPackageName();
            final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Requesting ignore battery optimization");
                try {
                    // ignoring battery optimizations required for constant connection
                    // to peripheral device - eg CGM transmitter.
                    final Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Device does not appear to support battery optimization whitelisting!");
                }
            }
        }

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                statusMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(MedtronicCnlIntentService.Constants.ACTION_STATUS_MESSAGE));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                new UpdatePumpReceiver(),
                new IntentFilter(MedtronicCnlIntentService.Constants.ACTION_UPDATE_PUMP));

        mEnableCgmService = Eula.show(this, prefs);

        IntentFilter batteryIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        batteryIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
        batteryIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        batteryIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY);
        registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, batteryIntentFilter);

        IntentFilter usbIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        usbIntentFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        usbIntentFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
        usbIntentFilter.addAction(MedtronicCnlIntentService.Constants.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        registerReceiver(usbReceiver, usbIntentFilter);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                usbReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(MedtronicCnlIntentService.Constants.ACTION_NO_USB_PERMISSION));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                usbReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(MedtronicCnlIntentService.Constants.ACTION_USB_REGISTER));

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nightscout");
        }

        final PrimaryDrawerItem itemSettings = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Settings")
                .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings)
                .withSelectable(false);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem itemRegisterUsb = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Registered devices")
                .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_usb)
                .withSelectable(false);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem itemStopCollecting = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Stop collecting data")
                .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_power_settings_new)
                .withSelectable(false);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem itemGetNow = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Read data now")
                .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_refresh)
                .withSelectable(false);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem itemUpdateProfile = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Update pump profile")
                .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_insert_chart)
                .withSelectable(false);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem itemClearLog = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Clear log")
                .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_clear_all)
                .withSelectable(false);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem itemCheckForUpdate = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Check for App update")
                .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_update)
                .withSelectable(false);

        assert toolbar != null;
        new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withAccountHeader(new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                        .withActivity(this)
                        .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.drawer_header)
                        .build()
                )
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withSelectedItem(-1)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        itemSettings,
                        //itemUpdateProfile, // TODO - re-add when we to add Basal Profile Upload
                        itemRegisterUsb,
                        itemCheckForUpdate,
                        itemClearLog,
                        itemGetNow,
                        itemStopCollecting
                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        if (drawerItem.equals(itemSettings)) {
                            openSettings();
                        } else if (drawerItem.equals(itemRegisterUsb)) {
                            openUsbRegistration();
                        } else if (drawerItem.equals(itemStopCollecting)) {
                            mEnableCgmService = false;
                            stopCgmService();
                            finish();
                        } else if (drawerItem.equals(itemGetNow)) {
                            // It was triggered by user so start reading of data now and not based on last poll.
                            sendStatus("Requesting poll now...");
                            startCgmService(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000);
                        } else if (drawerItem.equals(itemClearLog)) {
                            clearLogText();
                        } else if (drawerItem.equals(itemCheckForUpdate)) {
                            checkForUpdateNow();
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();

        mTextViewLog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_log);
        mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        mScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

        mChart = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        // disable scrolling at the moment
        mChart.getViewport().setScalable(false);
        mChart.getViewport().setScrollable(false);
        mChart.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
        mChart.getViewport().setMinY(80);
        mChart.getViewport().setMaxY(120);
        mChart.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
        final long now = System.currentTimeMillis(),
                left = now - chartZoom * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        mChart.getViewport().setMaxX(now);
        mChart.getViewport().setMinX(left);

// due to bug in GraphView v4.2.1 using setNumHorizontalLabels reverted to using v4.0.1 and setOnXAxisBoundsChangedListener is n/a in this version
/*
        mChart.getViewport().setOnXAxisBoundsChangedListener(new Viewport.OnXAxisBoundsChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onXAxisBoundsChanged(double minX, double maxX, Reason reason) {
                double rightX = mChart.getSeries().get(0).getHighestValueX();
                hasZoomedChart = (rightX != maxX || rightX - chartZoom * 60 * 60 * 1000 != minX);
            }
        });
*/
        mChart.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (!mChart.getSeries().isEmpty() && !mChart.getSeries().get(0).isEmpty()) {
                    double rightX = mChart.getSeries().get(0).getHighestValueX();
                    mChart.getViewport().setMaxX(rightX);
                    mChart.getViewport().setMinX(rightX - chartZoom * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                }
                hasZoomedChart = false;
                return true;
            }
        });
        mChart.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(6);

// due to bug in GraphView v4.2.1 using setNumHorizontalLabels reverted to using v4.0.1 and setHumanRounding is n/a in this version
//        mChart.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);

        mChart.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(
                new DefaultLabelFormatter() {
                    DateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);  // 24 hour format forced to fix label overlap

                    @Override
                    public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
                        if (isValueX) {
                            return mFormat.format(new Date((long) value));
                        } else {
                            return MainActivity.strFormatSGV(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Here is the logcat output:

```
09-26 12:38:19.826 6324-6324/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-26 12:38:20.157 6324-6324/info.nightscout.android E/Fabric: Failure onPreExecute()
                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following tag to your Application element 
                                                                <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.logErrorOrThrowException(ApiKey.java:110)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.getValue(ApiKey.java:61)
                                                                   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:219)
                                                                   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:207)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:440)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:384)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:342)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:313)
                                                                   at info.nightscout.android.UploaderApplication.onCreate(UploaderApplication.java:32)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1046)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5402)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
09-26 12:38:20.202 6324-6379/info.nightscout.android E/Fabric: Error dealing with settings
                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following tag to your Application element 
                                                                <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.logErrorOrThrowException(ApiKey.java:110)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.getValue(ApiKey.java:61)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.initialize(Settings.java:78)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:124)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
09-26 12:38:20.252 6324-6324/info.nightscout.android W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-26 12:38:20.349 6324-6324/info.nightscout.android I/MainActivity: onCreate called
09-26 12:38:20.652 6324-6324/info.nightscout.android D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-26 12:38:20.652 6324-6324/info.nightscout.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: info.nightscout.android, PID: 6324
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.nightscout.android/info.nightscout.android.medtronic.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at info.nightscout.android.medtronic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:349)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Post the logcat output.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Logcat output posted now.

Comment: where did you initialize btnSend button

Comment: I didn't see btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BTN_SEND_ID);  this kind of line

Comment: There we have it! I was experimenting with sending data with the push of a button, and I forgot to delete all code related to that. It no longer crashes, THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

Move the code `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
under the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Yes Superb:):):)

Comment: Thanks:) But that didn't keep it from crashing unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you are mapping the views before adding layout in your code.
your onCreate() should be

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate called");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   //Do mapping all views
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Error log is showing you your solution. The project is using Fabric API. So naturally you need to add Fabric API key to your project.

Do as suggested in Error log. Add following line in Android Manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

For your API key, make a project using Fabric account and get your API key.